# How to add and remove the class when clicked

Tags: javascript

There is a problem when using animate.css. How do I make when you click on the button class is added and after the animation - removed?

HTML:

```
<div></div>
<button>Click</button>
```

JavaScript

```
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  div.classList.add('animated', 'bounceInDown');
});
```

Link to the [sandbox](http://jsbin.com/xomututine/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Have you got any method to detect if the animation is finished? (like a event)

Comment: Method can be used to calculate the duration getComputedStyle animation (animation-duration). But then I can not figure out how to remove then.

Comment: I edited my answer. Check it out (I think is a solution, although a dirty solution)

Comment: Use the `animationEnd` event. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `classList.toggle` method:

```
document.querySelector('.element').classList.toggle('class');
```

This line add/remove the class from the element.

**MORE DETAILS FOR ONE (DIRTY) SOLUTION:**

```
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  div.classList.add('animated', 'bounceInDown');
  setTimeout(deleteClass, 1000);

});

function deleteClass(){
    console.log("Test");
    div.classList.add('animated', 'bounceInDown');
    div.classList.remove('animated', 'bounceInDown');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction and for the positive vote ^^

Comment: You misunderstood. I mean, when you click on the button you must first add a class for animation, then, after the end of the animation class to delete.

Comment: Hmm... sorry I didn't understand you. I'm thinking now.

Comment: Well, this is quite fragile. It assumes that the animation lasts exactly 1 second. Every time the animation duration is changed you'll have to remember to come back to this code and fix the constant 1000. Better to use an event notifying you of the end of the animation.

Comment: You're right... But I don't know other solution. May you post one solution with an event?  (I hope not seem annoying: my english isn't very good)

Comment: @torazaburo, you mean like this: http://jsbin.com/ramiqopixe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: BTW, `classList.add` and `classList.remove` do not support multiple classes according to the spec. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/common-dom-interfaces.html#domtokenlist-0. It appears to work in Chrome, but not in IE.